# React three fiber, fbx model is taking too long to load

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I just started working with threejsfiber and I'm having some problems with the 3D model loading, or this is what I think is the problem. Here is the code:

```
    const Scene = () => {
      let fbx = useFBX("FLEX2_matselections.fbx");

      return <primitive object={fbx} scale={0.03} />;
    };
    
export default function MainPage() {
  return (
    <div className='background-main-page'>
      <h1 className='mainpage-hacking-text'>
        This is the limited edition of NFT sneakers collectible.
        <br /> There are only 10.000 pieces in the entire world.
        <br /> The sneakers are in both, phisical and digital fo
      </h1>
      <Canvas className='canvas'>
        <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[17, 2, 3]} />
        <OrbitControls
          autoRotate
          enableZoom={false}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2.8}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2.8}
        />
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Scene />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The thing is I want to animate the text inside the h1 tag, but the animation is being stop when the model is loading, making a terrible UX. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compress your gltfs with gltf-pipeline and dracos highest compression level.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).